# Stationary State and Phase Change

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In a stationary state like $e^{-i \omega t} \phi(x)$, the norm square is the square of the energy function and the exponential term only represents phase change/rotation. What exactly is the physical meaning of the rotation of a particle? Does the rotation specify angular momentum?